# C# - How to read what a text box starts with?

Tags: c#

So what I am looking for is something like this:

If a text box starts with 'www.' or 'http://' or 'https://' then run

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(toolStripTextBox1.Text);
```

For an example.
So it would end up looking something like this (I'm not fully sure.)

```
if(toolStripTextBox1.Text == "www." + anything)
```

These are just examples. I really have no idea...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037445/c-sharp-string-contains This may help you. The StartsWith function seems more useful tho. See below.

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio, I would suggest you familiarize yourself with how to use Intellisense effectively. Many of these types of operations exist already, and are named fairly intuitively, as you can see with `StartsWith`. There is also `EndsWith`, `Contains`, `IsNullOrEmpty`, etc. just for strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [String.StartsWith()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith(v=vs.110).aspx) method in your case:

```
if(toolStripTextBox1.Text.StartsWith("www."))
```

Comment: thanks, i knew there was a startswith function but i had no idea how to use it :) works great.

Comment: If that helped, you could accept it as an answer then. Good luck.

Comment: I tried to but it said I had to wait 11 minutes, I did now im pretty sure

Answer (score 3):

Judging by your examples, you want to check whether or not the use has entered a valid URL. Checking the string manually is not the correct way to do it.

You should instead try to parse an [`Uri`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) object using [`Uri.TryCreate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131572(v=vs.110).aspx). If it succeeds - you know the user entered a valid URL. You can then use the created `uri` as an argument to [`WebBrowser.Navigate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161352(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Uri uri;
if(Uri.TryCreate(toolStripTextBox1.Text, UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate(uri);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C# has a `startswith` function for strings.  So

```
if(toolStripTextBox1.Text.Startswith("www.")) 
{  ..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to do something like the following:

```
if (toolStripTextBox1.Text.StartsWith("www."))
{
    // do something
}
```

The [String.StartsWith method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith(v=vs.110).aspx) will give you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
string text = toolStripTextBox1.Text;
if (text.StartsWith("www.") || text.StartsWith("http://") || text.StartsWith("https://"))
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate(text);
}
```

However, I recommend using [Uri.IsWellFormedUriString Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring.aspx) if you are checking if the textbox text is a valid URL.

```
if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(text, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
```

Answer (score 0):

Or for a more Complex search you can use the REGEX CLASS [SOURCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

String myString = toolStripTextBox1.Text;
Regex myRegex = new Regex(@"www.\S+");
Match myMatches = myRegex.Match(myString);
if(myMatches.Groups.Count>0)return true;
```

[ONLINE EXAMPLE](https://www.myregextester.com/?r=df08eb14)

Comment: Why would you use regex for *that*? ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @GediminasMasaitis - If the name of the textbox is "word before www.exemple.com", text.Startswith will not work so Regex would be a great option, and if he need the name of the web link he will be able to have it  !