# Merging two String.Compare substrings into one

Tags: c#, .net, string

So i am checking if selected string contains `substring + anything + substring1`, and now i am doing it like this:

```
if(line.Contains("2-") && line.Contains(":"))
{
    //work
}
```

Is there any other way like `line.Contains("2-[somesign]:")` or anyting like that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# String contains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037445/c-sharp-string-contains)

Comment: You are looking for regular expressions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You can check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16037705/3025545 overrides `contains` method to work with multiple parameters.

Comment: Those aren't the same operations. Your original code matches ":2-" but the pattern you propose does not.  So which is it? Is the original code wrong?

Comment: @EricLippert you are right it needs to match only ':' after '2-', but there will be no strings like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regular expression is a good solution.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

if(Regex.IsMatch(@"2-.*:"))
{
    //work
}
```

This will match `any_string1 + "2-" + any_string2 + ":" + any_string3`.

This addresses the concern mentioned in the comments where using `contains` will not differentiate the order of the `"2-"` and the `":"`.

Comment: just `"2-.*:"` is enough

Answer (score 2):

If the order does not matter, then calling `Contains` multiple times is fine. Else, you can create an extension method like this:

```
public static class StringExtension
{
    public static bool ContainsInOrder(this string value, params string[] args)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || args == null || args.Length == 0)
            return false;

        int previousIndex = -1;
        foreach (string arg in args)
        {
            if (arg == null) return false;

            int index = value.IndexOf(arg);
            if (index == -1 || index < previousIndex)
            {
                return false;
            }
            previousIndex = index;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
"hello, world".ContainsInOrder("hello", ",", "world"); // true
"hello, world".ContainsInOrder("hello", null, "world"); // false
"hello, world".ContainsInOrder("hello", ":", "world"); // false
"hello, world".ContainsInOrder("hello", "world"); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   class Program {
      static void Main(String[] args) {
         // By using extension methods
         if ( "Hello world".ContainsAll(StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase, "Hello", "world") ) 
            Console.WriteLine("Found everything by using an extension method!");
         else 
            Console.WriteLine("I didn't");

         // By using a single method
         if ( ContainsAll("Hello world", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase, "Hello", "world") )
            Console.WriteLine("Found everything by using an ad hoc procedure!");
         else 
            Console.WriteLine("I didn't");

      }

      private static Boolean ContainsAll(String str, StringComparison comparisonType, params String[] values) {
         return values.All(s => s.Equals(s, comparisonType));
      }    
   }

   // Extension method for your convenience
   internal static class Extensiones {
      public static Boolean ContainsAll(this String str, StringComparison comparisonType, params String[] values) {
         return values.All(s => s.Equals(s, comparisonType));
      }
   }
```