# detect key press

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I have a code where I do something when a Key is pressed

```
if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.G)
{
    Logger.Trace("Opening the GUI...");
}
```

How to detect if key is pressed by using character as `A-B`? I store shortcut letter in file and want to know if pressed but need to detect it by `string` and not `ConsoleKey`.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please try to correct the grammar.

Comment: add format and remove unnecessary

Answer (score 2):

You can use **`char.IsLetter()`**  to check if its an alphabet

```
    ConsoleKeyInfo keyinfo;
    Console.ReadKey();
    while (!(Console.KeyAvailable  ))
    {
        keyinfo = Console.ReadKey();
        if (char.IsLetter(Console.ReadKey().KeyChar))
        {  
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the Console.ReadKey result into a string variable and append further keystrokes and check with

```
if(inputString.Contains(key)){
  doSomething()
}
```

Have a look at the following answers:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16037492/4992212

[Detect when two keys are pressed at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536368/detect-when-two-keys-are-pressed-at-the-same-time)